# face problem to import css, js files link in django

Tags: python, css, django

I am a newbie in Django 2.11.1 and using macbook as my platform. I have a problem to link my css, images and js to django templage,I tryies several methods whether to change the code in setting.py, or run 'python manage.py collectstatic --noinput',the result is I can the path of the css and js files are right, I can trace them in the "http://127.0.0.1:8000/become-a-host/index", but they doesn't have an impact on the visual effect of the websites, apparently they don't work, I don't know why.
Here is my project structure
sentiment_analysis

```
|-zeta
| |-.vscode
| |-users
| |-manage.py
| |-venv
| |-static
| |-zeta
| | |-_pycache_
| | |-__init__.py
| | |-setting.py 
| | |-wsgi.py 
| | |-urls.py 
| |-advertising
| | |-_pycache_
| | |-migrations
| | |-__init__.py 
| | |-admin.py 
| | |-models.py 
| | |-tests.py 
| | |-urls.py 
| | |-views.py 
| | |-tests.py 
| | |-app.py
| |-templates
| | |-advertising
| | | |-index.html
| | |-users 

setting.py 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/Users/zachary/lecture/9900/zeta/static/',
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( 
    '/advertising/templates', 
)
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/zachary/lecture/9900/zeta/static_root/'

url.py
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

base.html
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  {% load staticfiles %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/icomoon.css'%}"  type='test/css'/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}" type='test/css'/>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]. You are not showing relevant code nor a stack error, and is not clear what you mean by "import", so we won't be able to help you until you fix these issues.

Comment: Please post at least your settings.py file and your template.

Comment: They go in the static folder

Comment: Thanks for u guys, I have a already post the code.

Answer (score 0):

They do not have a visual effect, because you misspelled the mime type of the CSS files:

```
type='test/css'
```

Should be:

```
type='text/css'
```